Why isn't my list adding the final node after the carry?
I am currently attempting to answer the question Add Two Numbers from leetcode, my solution seems to function as I expect however in cases where my final carry int is needed it is not added to the end of my list in the final if statement.
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        int carry = 0;
        ListNode* ans = l1;
        while(l1 || l2){
            if(l1 == nullptr) l1 = new ListNode();
            if(l1 == nullptr && l2){
                l1 -> val = (l2 -> val + carry) % 10;
                carry = (carry + l2 -> val) / 10;
                l2 = l2 -> next;
            }else if(l2 == nullptr && l1){
                int tempL1Val = l1 -> val;
                l1 -> val = (l1 -> val + carry) % 10;
                carry = (carry + tempL1Val) / 10;
            }else{
                int tempL1Val = l1 -> val;
                l1 -> val = (l1 -> val + l2 -> val + carry) % 10;
                carry = (tempL1Val + l2 -> val + carry) / 10;
                l2 = l2 -> next;
            }
            l1 = l1 -> next;
        }
        
        if(carry){
            l1 = new ListNode();
            l1 -> val = carry;
        } 
        return ans;
    }
};

Testcases where it fails:
l1 = [9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
l2 = [9,9,9,9]
output = [8,9,9,9,0,0,0]
expected_output = [8,9,9,9,0,0,0,1]


I have checked before and after and the new node does exist, however it is not being added to my list when I run the code.

Recommendation: Add a main function that calls your code and feeds in one of the failure cases. This makes it easier on everyone, the can drop the code into their tools, see what you see (Mostly), and experiment with it. With a canned example that autoruns the test set you can very quickly run the program over and over in a debugger and watch exactly what happens as it happens until you understand the problem.

you can try adding a pointer to keep track of the previous node.  you're not properly updating the next pointers of the nodes. When you add a new node to the end of the list, you need to update the next pointer of the current last node to point to the new node.

Why are you trying to learn C++ by competitive coding (Leetcode) and then start asking questions here (instead of at the leetcode forum)? Competitive coding is about the WORST way to learn a language. What leetcode calls a List isn't a list, C++ has std::list for that

So my advice stop competitive coding, and learn C++ first. E.g. go through the training material at learncpp.com. Then investigate cppreference to learn what kind of building blocks C++ offers you (a lot!!). And finally read the C++ core guidelines to really get to know how C++ is supposed to be used today (there are lot of examples out there that are just outdated). One of C++'s guidelines is to avoid new/delete and in most cases naked pointers.

Making this simple example (https://godbolt.org/z/319hq85fP) shows something interesting: A memory leak at l1 = new ListNode();. Because of the ~ListNode() { delete next; } freeing the node after it in the list we can infer that the leaked node was never added to the list. So ask yourself, is l1 in the list at all or is it just a pointer that happened to point at an item in the list at one time?

Anyway, if you make and instrument a good example, the error often becomes obvious. This is the most important reason why Stack Overflow expects a [mre] (MRE) to come with every debugging question. Questions with a good MRE are usually good, well thought out questions be cause there was still a question left after the asker debugged their code. Questions without a MRE on the other hand...

'Why isn't my list adding the final node?'. Posted code shows no attempt to add the final node to the list. Conclusion, sometimes you just have to develop the ability to see your own code clearly.

At the moment, you are creating the new node, but not adding it to your list.
As it needs to go at the end of your list, you need to know the current end of the list, so you can add the item onto it.
You can either:

Find the end of the list by starting at the original start of l1 (which you have saved in ans) and looping forward via next

or, as you are already looping through l1 in your existing loop, keep track of the last node in the l1 list (e.g. save l1 in another variable before the l1 = l1->next line)



It is leetcode that gets things wrong by not using the C++ standard library. With std::list you almost can't go wrong, you just call std::list::push_back.

I agree - this would be much easier using the standard library and this approach wouldn't be acceptable for any production code. However I took this question to mean the OP is  learning how to maintain lists etc, rather than writing any long lived code.

Another good trick, and it avoids having to track the previous node, is to store a pointer to the next pointer of the previous node. This not only gives you a pointer to the current node, but it also gives you a pointer to the insertion point of the previous node. Everybody wins!

Agree with  user4581301 , but you had better make your node struct have 2 pointer: *next and *previous,  or try to remember previous node by yourself.

You are right to check if carry is more than 0 after the loop. However, you didn't successfully append the ListNode that you created to the end of the linked list.
To do that, you need to have access to the last element of the linked list. But now you are beyond that, so you need to trace back to the part where you do have access to the final node. This is during the final iteration of the while loop. So, I suggest you add this piece of code there:
if (l1->next == nullptr && carry) {
      l1 -> next = new ListNode();
      l1 -> next -> val = 1;
      break;
} 

and remove the if (carry) check you have at the end.
I believe there might be some other issues with your code (HINT: it might not work if l2 is longer than l1) but this probably answers your question.

@ick1salvado, don't get discouraged by the comments above. Leetcode is a pretty decent way to learn to code. But I have to admit, manipulating a linked list in C++ is quite tough. I recommend you to master linked lists in Python first (as you don't have to think about pointers etc.) and then use the same logic to solve the problem in C++.

No it is not! Leetcode learns you how to solve puzzles and create algorithms (just a part of coding). You really have no idea how bad the programming style is you pickup on those sites. If you would do that kind of coding at work you will not pass any code review.

Leetcode and friends are decent practice, and fun if you like solving puzzles, once you have the fundamental skills down. Without those fundamentals they're mostly a source of frustration as you slowly teach yourself those fundamentals. Save yourself the time and start learning from a good book or two or some other high-quality guided information source.

Well, I didn't say it's the best way to learn to code and you're right, Leetcode can't teach you how to organise your code and follow best practices. But at least it helps you develop algorithmic thinking, which guides you in assuring the correctness of your code.

No argument from me on the algorithm side :) But being a programmer really means you have to be able to follow the languages guidelines and being able to write maintainable (readable!!) and unit testable code (without tricks or hacks).

The big trick about pointers is the pointer is a reference to some other object. Through the pointer, you can change the other object. But the pointer itself is just like every other variable. It's just a value, and that value is the location of some other object. Copy a pointer and you get just that: a copy. Two completely different variables that just happen to have the same value. if you have to change the pointer itself, change where it points, you need another level of indirection, a reference or a pointer to the pointer.

In my opinion, LeetCode 2. Add Two Numbers is an example of LeetCode at its worst. It encourages programmers not to worry about memory leaks. The consequences of such "training" can be disastrous. The history of C++ is replete with many examples of serious system failures and exploits caused by memory leaks.

You have to understand the ListNode first.
The basically ListNode have at least 2 parameters, one is value, another is the pointer of the next ListNode.
If you new a new node , you have to let the next pointer of the previous node to point to it.
In your (carry) if block, I can't find any code can make previous node to pointer to this node.
It's much easy to read/understand :
        }else{
            int tmpVal = (l1 -> val + l2 -> val + carry);
            l1 -> val = tmpVal % 10;
            carry = tmpVal / 10;
            l2 = l2 -> next;
        }

l2 is to the end:
        }else if(l2 == nullptr && l1){
            int tmpVal = (l1 -> val + carry);
            l1 -> val =  tmpVal % 10;
            carry = tmpVal / 10;
        }else{ ...

About this :
        if(l1 == nullptr && l2){
            l1 -> val = (l2 -> val + carry) % 10;
            carry = (carry + l2 -> val) / 10;
            l2 = l2 -> next;
        }else if(l2 == nullptr && l1){

If l1 == nullptr, then you CAN NOT assign any value to it!
You have to create one new l1 node  to assign it's val and make previoud node to point to it !
        if(l1 == nullptr && l2){
            l1 = new ListNode();        // !!
            // but I can *NOT* make the `next` pointer of previous node to point to it !! 
            l1 -> val = (l2 -> val + carry) % 10;
            carry = (carry + l2 -> val) / 10;
            l2 = l2 -> next;
        }else if(l2 == nullptr && l1){ ...

Although I had new a l1 node here, but I have to make previous to know I am the next one node.
So, I have to make another pointer to remember the previous l1 node .
So, the code become :
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    int carry = 0;
    ListNode* ans = l1;
    ListNode* prevl1 = l1;   //// !!!! ++++  
    while(l1 || l2){
        // xx if(l1 == nullptr) l1 = new ListNode();
        if(l1 == nullptr && l2){    // It's IMPOSSIBLE to enter this block if previous line exist !!
        // Because `l1 = new ListNode()` at previous line, so it's *IMPOSSIBLE* `== nullptr` HERE !!! 
            l1 = new ListNode();    // !!
            prevl1->next = l1 ;     // !!
            l1 -> val = (l2 -> val + carry) % 10;
            carry = (carry + l2 -> val) / 10;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }else if(l2 == nullptr && l1){
            int tmpVal = l1->val + carry;
            l1->val = tmpVal  % 10;
            carry = tmpVal  / 10;
        }else{
            int tmpVal = l1->val + l2->val + carry;
            l1 -> val = tmpVal  % 10;
            carry = tmpVal  / 10;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        prevl1  = l1;
        l1 = l1->next; 
    }
    
    if(carry){
        l1 = new ListNode();
        l1->val = carry;
        prevl1->next = l1;     // !! 
    } 
    return ans;
}

